# React-native: tvOS How to set focus on specific item in list view?

Tags: listview, react-native, tvos, apple-tv, touchablehighlight

I write an tvOS app with react native and I have few list view, I want to set focus on specific item in list view ?

It is possible ?

Answer (score 1):

With tvOS and react native if you want to force a focusable component to be focus you just need to set hasTVPreferredFocus with the value of true

Let me show you an example:

```
<TouchableHighlight
    hasTVPreferredFocus={true}
    onPress={() => {}}
>
    <Text>Hello</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```